# C#: How to Serialize RenderFragment (Razor template)?

Tags: c#, razor, json.net, signalr, blazor

Im working on a Blazor Wasm Hosted (client and server) project to render dynamic razor components loaded from dlls. I tried to send the components to the client via SignalR but failed because of `System.Type`. That is why I decided to create the render tree `RenderFragment` from dynamic component at the server-side instead, then serialize and send it to the client to render the component in razor page. But I get an error when serializing `RenderFragment`. How to fix this error?

The function below creates the render tree from `IDynamicComponent` to `RenderFragment`, then serializes it to string which **produces the error**. After that It sends the string to the client via SignalR.

```
public async Task GetPlugin()
{
    try
    {
        // Build the render tree of the component
        RenderFragment renderFragment = builder => {
            
            // Gets the component by name
            IDynamicComponent component = ComponentService.GetComponentByName("Counter");
    
            builder.OpenComponent(0, component.Component);
    
            for (int i = 0; i < component.Parameters.Count; i++)
            {
                var attribute = component.Parameters.ElementAt(i);
                builder.AddAttribute(i + 1, attribute.Key, attribute.Value);
            }
        };
        
        // Serialize the renderfragment to string
        string componentFragment = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(renderFragment); // Error occurs here
        
        // Send to client
        await myHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("Plugin", componentFragment);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Error Output:**

This error occurs when serializing the `RenderFragment`

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: This instance contains state that cannot be serialized and deserialized on this platform.
   at System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.OnSerializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
```

**Additional Information**

The components are created using the `IDynamicComponent` Interface below:

```
public interface IDynamicComponent
{
    IDictionary<Type,Type> InjectableDependencies { get; }
    IDictionary<string,string> Parameters { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    Type Component { get;}
}
```

**Component Example** (Razor Class Library)

MyComponent.cs

```
public class MyComponent : IDynamicComponent
{
    public IDictionary<Type, Type> InjectableDependencies => new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
    public IDictionary<string, string> Parameters => new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public string Name => "Example1";
    public Type Component => typeof(Component1);  // Component1.razor

}
```

Component1.razor

```
<h1>Counter</h1>
<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can deserialize an interface? ( `IDictionary` )

Comment: I think if I create the render tree from `IDynamicComponent` component it becomes `RenderFragment` which can directly be used to render the UI in razor. The issue Im having is serializing it to string to send it to the client-side because my project is Blazor Wasm Hosted. Its got both client(wasm) and server project.

Comment: A RenderFragment is a Delegate. Aside from the technical issues in serializing that, this is a very strange architecture. The razor code belongs in the View, the data comes from the API. So why do (you think) you need to do UI in the backend?

Comment: The reason why Im creating the `RenderFragment` at the server-side is that the `IDynamicComponent` contains component of `System.Type`. I tried to serialize `IDynamicComponent` but was unsuccessful, that is why I thought I might have a chance converting it to render tree object then serializing it. In your opinion, what should I do?

Comment: I have added how I create the component. Could you check and see how I can add the razor component to `MyComponent` without using `System.Type`. My intention is to be able to serialize it once I load its dll, and send to client from server. Any ideas on how to modify the `IDynamicComponent` interface to allow serialization?